# in angular2 while import ngx-store in appmodule.ts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html:54 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56455/src/ngx-store
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56455/src/ngx-store
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn 
    Error loading http://localhost:56455/src/ngx-store as "ngx-store" from http://localhost:56455/src/app/app.module.js

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't configured systemjs correctly to setup ngrx-store with systemjs use a config that has the following:

```
System.config({
    packages: {

        '@ngrx/store': {
            main: 'dist/index.js',
            format: 'cjs'           
        },
        '@ngrx/devtools': {
            main: 'dist/index.js',
            format: 'cjs'
        } 
    },
    map: {
        '@ngrx': 'node_modules/@ngrx'
    }
});
```